# how to add a photo in a desired position of a frame?

Tags: android, image, imageview, mask

I am trying to :

1. Pick a photo from Android gallery (Suppose : **person.png**)
2. Cropping the photo as rounded image
3. Resize the image in **300x300** pixels
4. Then add the resized image(**person.png**) on the top of a frame image (**frame.png**). And the final resulted image will look like this (**final_image.png**)
5. Then, save the new image(**final_image.png**) into gallery with a new name.

[image: person.png]

**person.png**

[image: frame.png]

**frame.png**

[image]

**final_image.png**

Here is my demo code for loading an image in a frame or mask.

```
    ImageView mImageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview_id);
 Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.content_image);
 Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.mask);
 Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
 Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(result);
 Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
 paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
 mCanvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
 mCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
 paint.setXfermode(null);
 mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
 mImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
 mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_frame);
```

Comment: How does the result of the example code differ from what you actually want?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I was asking myself the same question as OP when I saw this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKNPfO6qjk0 .... I was hoping you could help me figure out how the manage to take the picture programmatically in a given frame

Comment: @KurtMiller Please take a moment to read [ask] and then post a new question by clicking the Ask Question button at the top right.